# What is the alternative to an <iframe> in sharepoint

Tags: 2010, html, iframe

I have tried time and time again to hardcode an `<iframe>` into one of my Sharepoint 2010 pages. It looks brilliant until I save and close, when I do sharepoint removes any trace of an `<iframe>`.

**My Question:**

Is there any way to force sharepoint to allow iFrames? If not is there an alternative and how would I go about doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: To help other answers... how do you added the IFrame? Designer, content editor etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Page Viewer web part (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527 ). It uses an iframe.

Comment: The link provided in the solution was broken

Comment: @TARUN do note, that the answer was given in 2012. The current URL - as of 06/2017 - would be https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add iframe directly onto the page's script, SharePoint will remove out unsafe html tags.
If you are using the latest SharePoint version, you can click on INSERT then click on Embed Code when editing any rich text field. In SharePoint 2010, you can only use Page Viewer Web Part.
[image]